# set_facts with dict as argument of a loop

Tags: list, loops, ansible

I'd like to obtain the list of bridged interfaces grouped by master like this:

```
brv100:
 - vnet0
 - eth0
brv101:
  - vnet1
  - eth1
```

I want to use native json output from the shell commands.
The only thing I managed to do is to get a predefined number of interfaces like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - shell:
        cmd: ip -details -pretty -json link show type bridge
      register: list_bridges

    - set_fact:
        bridges: "{{ list_bridges.stdout }}"

    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ bridges | map(attribute='ifname') | list}}"

    - name: get json
      shell:
        cmd: ip -details -pretty -json link show master "{{ifname}}"
      with_items: "{{bridges | map(attribute='ifname') | list}}" 
      loop_control:
        loop_var: ifname
      register: list_interfaces

    - set_fact:
        interfaces: "{{ list_interfaces.results | map(attribute='stdout') | list }}"

    - set_fact:
        toto: "{{interfaces.1}} + {{interfaces.2}}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{toto | map(attribute='ifname')|list}}"
```

Now if I want to do the same with a loop :

```
    - set_fact:
    toto: " {{item|default([])}}+ {{ item |default([])}}.{{idx}} "
  loop: "{{interfaces}}"
  loop_control:
   label: "{{item}}"
   index_var: idx
   - debug: var=toto
```

The result doesn't seem to be a list of list, but a list of strings and I can't extract the 'ifname' values with a simple debug

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{toto | map(attribute='ifname')|list}}"
```

What am I supposed to do so as to get benefit of the json native output and get simple list of bridged interfaces (like brctl show was used to do)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lists of bridged interfaces grouped by the master are available in `ansible_facts`. The task below sets the dictionary of the bridges and bridged interfaces

```
- set_fact:
    bridges: "{{ dict(ansible_facts|
                 dict2items|
                 json_query('[?value.type == `bridge`].[key, value.interfaces]')) }}"
```

> Q: *"Manage to get the same result manipulating JSON data."*

A: The output of the `ip -json ...` command is JSON formated string which must be converted to JSON dictionary in Ansible by the `from_yaml` filter (JSON is a subset of YAML). For example, the tasks below give the same result

```
  vars:

    my_debug: false

  tasks:

    - name: Get bridges names
      command: "ip -details -json link show type bridge"
      register: list_bridges
    - set_fact:
        bridges: "{{ list_bridges.stdout|
                     from_yaml|
                     map(attribute='ifname')|
                     list }}"
    - debug:
        var: bridges
      when: my_debug

    - name: Get bridges interfaces
      command: "ip -details -json link show master {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ bridges }}" 
      register: list_interfaces
    - set_fact:
        bridges_interfaces: "{{ list_interfaces.results|
                                json_query('[].stdout')|
                                map('from_yaml')|
                                list }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ msg.split('\n') }}"
      vars:
        msg: "{{ item|to_nice_yaml }}"
      loop: "{{ bridges_interfaces }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item|json_query('[].ifname') }}"
      when: my_debug

    - name: Set dictionary of bridges
      set_fact:
        bridges_dict: "{{ bridges_dict|
                          default({})|
                          combine({item.0: item.1|json_query('[].ifname')}) }}"
      loop: "{{ bridges|zip(bridges_interfaces)|list }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.1|json_query('[].ifname') }}"
    - debug:
        var: bridges_dict
```

---

Template to write the bridges to a file

```
{% for k,v in bridges_dict.items() %}
{{ k }}:
{% if v is iterable %}
{% for i in v %}
  - {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

```
    - name: Write the bridges to file
      template:
        src: bridges.txt.j2
        dest: bridges.txt
```

The file `bridges.txt` will be created in the remote host running the task.

Comment: Thanks, the solution is very easy, using ansible_facts formatted json. But what about dealing with different json inputs, like shell output of ip command? I can't by anyway manage to get the same result manipulating json data that begin with "[{". I was convinced that using json input was an advantage, but it seems that it needs a lot of transformations before getting the wanted display result. I would be pleased to know if such a tentative is possible.

Comment: The `json data that begin with "[{"` is a string, not a JSON. This is the source of troubles. Command `ip -details -json ...` returns JSON formatted string. Convert it to YAML. For example `list_bridges.stdout|from_yaml`.

Comment: Very interested way, I learned a lot from your code and how to use json_query. Now I tried to get the same result by a jinja2 template: `{% for bridge in bridges %}
- {{ bridge }}:    
{% for interface in interfaces %}
{% if interface|json_query('[].master') ==  bridge %}
    {{ interface|json_query('[].ifname') }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}` without any success... Do you have an idea?

Comment: The result of json_query is a list. The condition can't compare a list with string. Use `{% if interface|json_query('[].master')|first == bridge %}`. But, I'd rather use `bridges_dict` for this purpose.

Comment: I've added to the answer an example of the template.

Comment: This template is acceptable, but it must deal with empty list, so _omit_ filter is needed: `{% if interface|json_query('[].master')|first|default(omit) == bridge %}`

Comment: Good catch. An empty list is a problem. I'd prefer `bridges_dict` and test value is iterable. I've updated the template in the answer. Thank you for the suggestions.